# Default state of the systray icon

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, trayicon, systray

In my WPF application, I had to set a systray icon. It's a business application which will be used every days.

In win 7(maybe vista, i don't know), Some icons can be hidden, displayed only when notifications, always displayed. Is it possible to indicate directly that my systray icon has to be always displayed? Otherwise, my customer will have to set this on every workstation it installs this program

Thank you!

Comment: No it should not be possible. You can always use balloons to notify the user of information.

Comment: No! you cannot make the notification icon to always visible. Instead, You can do following steps for it: 1. Right click o Timer Control in Taskbar and select "Customize Notification icon".   2. Check the checkbox "Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar"

Comment: I know that, but the customer will have to do this on his 800 computers. And this is not for information, this is to display the program, so a balloon isn't working for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. You can see [Raymond](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/15/10105142.aspx) thoughts on this.

Comment: Yeah I thought to that, but why the programm can't ask to the user to have his icon displayed by default? Like this, the user can directly at the installation/first launch indicate if he wants to display the icon without going into the menu, finding the right icon, ...

Comment: I think the best you can do is show a window that gives the user instructions on how to set your icon as always visible. See [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-how-icons-appear-in-the-notification-area), specifically the "To change how icons and notifications appear in the notification area" section.